# How to get most repetitive values with Eloquent?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have relation many to many (posts and tags) in `Eloquent`. Is it possible to order tags in the pivot table to get 10 most commonly used tags?

[image: pivot]

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, add some kind of attribute (to the pivot table and update it upon every select from the database. (increment the value)

And when selecting use wherePivot method.

If you want "most recent used", add timestamps to the pivot table in your migration and touch pivot table on every select.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is actually very simple to do that.

In the table that you store your tags add another column called `count_cache`(or whatever you want), then every time you add a tag instance to a post instance do a `count()` of the `tag_id` in the pivot table and store the value to the `count_cache` column in the tags table.

Then you can simply get the tags table ordered by the `count_cache` column (descending) with a limit of 10.

If you need further explanation please make a comment :)

Comment: the idea is clear but how to do it? I need somehow trigger incrementation on `sync` method.

Comment: Please provide more info, post your  related controller,your models or your repositories if any so I may help you.

Comment: what for ? I use `sync` method to add tags to posts. So I just need somehow to trigger custom method when `sync` is called

Comment: sync will overwrite all the previous relations with your tags and accept an array of the new relations. It's better to use attach if you want to update your model's relationship if you don't want to lose the previous relationships with your model.
The general idea is to calculate (count) how many occurrences of an id exists in the pivot table and then save that value to your tag table in a separate column so you don't have to calculate it every time.
You can always post some more code if you want something more than a general idea.

Comment: I know what `sync`, `attach`, `detach` methods are for. But I still need somehow to trigger when one of them is used.

Comment: Well, a logical place to store this code is in the function where you attach your post - tag relation. Or create another function that calculates the count of the tags and call it inside the function.
Or you can use laravel Events. For more info about events go [here](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/events)